# Why Silverlight doesnt include Messenger component?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

Why Silverlight doesnt include Messenger component? Silverlight tutorials advise using MVVM, but Silverlight itself doesnt have Messenger class by default, which is needed for MVVM apps. You have to download MVVM Light if you want to use Messenger. Will it be included in Silverlight 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Messenger class is not present out of box in WPF either, you will need to download some MVVM Toolkit (MVVM Light, Prism under *EventAggregator*) which provide this functionality. Microsoft does not include these components, because they are not so basic as they would need to be in the BCL and providing them outside the BCL (now I mean Prism, which I consider to be the closest to an "official" MVVM kit) it gives Microsoft more flexibility in updating these components.